# Use Django with MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a large mongo database with documents and i want to make Django website that is going to be a client to this mongo database but it can only filter (aggregate) and view information from database without any edit/update operations. I don't want to put other web site data (users' data, comments, other information) to mongo db. 
I'm new to django framework and i wonder if it is better to connect mongodb and django using, for example, mongoengine and use two databases (one for the web site data, and the second one for external documents in  mongodb) or use pymongo inside django to fetch data from external db and somehow transform it to djungo models?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you're spot on, in your case of needing two separate databases, it would be better to use mongoengine in order to use two separate databases. Check out this [link](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases). It goes over defining what database to use on a per-model basis so to say.

That most likely would work great. Basically you can query using the model the same way, regardless of the database is uses, but describe which database to use on the model itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. But it's still unclear to me if it is worth connecting mongodb to django if i need just send queries and view some filtered documents in a list on the website. Can't i fetch a dictionary using pymongo and send it to my template?

Comment: I mean for website data i can use pg or mysql

Comment: You certainly can fetch a dictionary using pymongo. I guess it comes down to whether you are looking for structured datasets in tabular form or just a free form database which is very flexible in terms of structuring. The answer  depends on what application you're trying to accomplish.